# Update or insert data from a table to another while the column name retrieved from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I want to implement is following: table target with columns my_index (primary key), updated_time, my_col_1, my_col_2, the data should look like following, and whenever a value comes into table source, the corresponding row in table target should be updated, and the updated_time as well. the columns would be just a sub set of the table def. So I think the table target needs to be created once the columns received from caller.

Table `target`:

```
my_index | updated_time            | ABC | DEF | GHI
---------+-------------------------+-----+-----+------
12       | 2021-05-11 01:01:01.000 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0
```

Table `source` with columns id (auto incr primary key), my_index, my_id, my_value, the data should look like this:

```
id | my_index | my_id | my_value
---+----------+-------+---------
1  | 12       | 3     | 1.0
2  | 12       | 4     | 2.0
3  | 12       | 5     | 3.0
4  | 11       | 6     | 4.0
```

while the columns in table target come from another table `def` with columns `my_id` (primary key), `my_col`, the data should look like this:

```
my_id | my_col
------+--------
3     | ABC
4     | DEF
5     | GHI
6     | JKL
```

I am not sure how to implement a SQL command to get data from table source, then update or insert into table target.

Could somebody kindly help? Appreciate it.

Comment: If you truly have no idea where to start, then SO is not the right place to get help. You really need a tutorial site of some sort. SO is for specific technical issues faced.

Comment: You have to join the table `source` with the table `another`, then pivot the `abc`,`def` and `ghi` rows into columns, then insert into the table `target`. You can write a single query (view) that pivots all the columns but to do the insert you need a query per target table or a dynamic sql. It might just be easier to do most of this in a front end language but if you're stuck in SQLS alone, maybe do the entire thing in a stored procedure if you have multiple target tables

Comment: @CaiusJard, thank you for your help. I am considering to create a trigger so that whenever any data inserted into table source, the table target should be updated. I am not sure if this is a correct way.

Comment: What is the purpose of this `target` table ? Is it for audit trail ?

Comment: Concur with the point Squirrel is getting at; all youre doing is storing same data the otherway round, which may be kinda pointless. Perhaps decide which way round is "best" for your 99% use case, and then generated it the other way round every time from a query for your 1%

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a very good data model - storing the names of columns in one table for updates in another is tricky.  SQL does not deal well with variable column names.

You can do what you want, but you have to list the columns explicitly.  The idea is to summarize the source table to get values for each potential column.  Then, set the value in the target column when there is a value in the source column:

```
update t
    set abc = (case when s.abc is not null then s.abc else t.abc end),
        def = (case when s.def is not null then s.def else t.def end),
        ghi = (case when s.ghi is not null then s.ghi else t.ghi end)        
    from target t join
         (select s.my_index,
                 max(case when d.my_col = 'ABC' then s.my_value end) as abc,
                 max(case when d.my_col = 'DEF' then s.my_value end) as def,
                 max(case when d.my_col = 'GHI' then s.my_value end) as ghi
          from source s join
               def d
               on s.my_id = d.my_id
          group by s.my_index
         ) s
         on s.my_index = t.my_index
```

Comment: thank you for your kind help. because of my heavy delivery stress, I chose to implement the logic through c#, however I believe the performance might be worse than using sql directly. I will come back and try your solution soon right after I finish the c# impl.